# How to show error messages in the from of popup

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms

i have one doubt hope you guys will clear ,

i have two text boxes one is user ID and one is User name in form i want to show error messages in the form of pop-up how to do in ASP.NET

Because i am very new ASP.net

Thank you

Comment: This is too genera question that need a lot of classifications, as you need to show the message after the post or before, do you use any javascript library ? The `alert("message")`, or the `confirm("are you sure?")` is not good to show that error/message ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example by assuming you are using javascript only:

```
<form method='post' onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-4">User Id: </label>
        <input type="text" id="UserId" name='UserId' placeholder="User ID">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-4">User Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="UserName" name='UserName' placeholder="User Name">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        function validateForm()
        {
            if ($("#UserId").val() && $("#UserName").val()) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Both User ID and User Name are required.")
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Hope this will guide you to implement further.